# Get name of person having activity in every month - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have log table where there is are records with user id and the date for a specific activity done. I want to get names of users having activity every month. I am using the following query

```
select distinct(employeeid) from transactions 
where eventdate between '01-OCT-13' AND '23-OCT-13'
and eventdate between '01-SEP-13' AND '01-OCT-13'
and eventdate between '01-AUG-13' AND '01-SEP-13'
and eventdate between '01-JUL-13' AND '01-AUG-13';
```

But this is doesn't work. Can someone please suggest any improvement?

**Edit:**
Since my questions seems to be a little confusing, here is an example

```
EmployeeID | Timestamp
a          | 01-Jul-13  
b          | 01-Jul-13  
a          | 01-Aug-13  
c          | 01-Aug-13  
a          | 01-Sep-13  
d          | 01-Sep-13  
a          | 01-Oct-13  
a          | 01-Oct-13
```

In the above table, we can see that employee "a" has activity in all the months from July till October. So I want to find a list of all such employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNT as analytical function and get the number of months for each employee and total number of months. Then select only those employees where both counts match.

```
select distinct employeeid
from (
    select employeeid,
           count(distinct trunc(eventdate,'month'))    --count of months for each employee
                 over (partition by employeeid) as emp_months,
           count(distinct trunc(eventdate,'month'))    --count of all months
                 over () as all_months,
    from transactions
    )
where emp_months = all_months;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramblin... It works great. But the problem is I have a database having about 200 million lines. So your query is taking about 6 hours to get the results. Is there any way I can speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could give you the code, but i'm in a bit of a hurry, so this is more of a suggestion.

Have you tried extracting the distinct months (from eventdate), for every user, and if that has 10 rows (assuming it is October, you could dynamically change this), then the employee must of had an event every month.

Comment: Could you maybe expand on this a little more now?

Answer (score 0):

By *very inefficient*, I think you mean *it doesn't work*. The same value can't be both in september, in october, etc.

Anyway, using @LaggKing suggestion, you could try this query:

```
SELECT employeeid
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, MONTH(eventdate)
 FROM transactions
)
HAVING COUNT(*) = MONTH(NOW())
```

**EDIT:** You need to take year into account.

```
SELECT employeeid
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, MONTH(eventdate)
 FROM transactions
 WHERE YEAR(eventdate) = YEAR(NOW())
)
HAVING COUNT(*) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: Could you, please, be more explicit? *Not working* = not the expected result? = syntax error?

Comment: Not working = Not expected result. Sorry for the misleading statement.

Comment: Answer edited, but it's still a guessing game, since I am not sure to understand what you exactly want.